# MVC asp.net VB syntax for default text for TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I set the default text (in a create view) for a TextBoxFor element:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.QualityM1s, New With {Key .text="0"})
```

Comment: It is not possible with '@Html.TextBoxFor(..)', if you want to set 'some value', if the model property doesn't have anything or null, where as you can do this with '@Html.TextBox(...)'. If you strictly want to use '@Html.TextBoxFor(..)', better you build your custom HTML Helper that does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by *default text*. If you want to preinitialize the textbox with some value you could use a normal textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.QualityM1s)
```

and then you could set the corresponding view model property to the default value inside your controller action just before passing the model to the view:

```
model.QualityM1s = "some default text"
return View(model)
```

The TextBoxFor helper will then use the value of your model property to fill the corresponding textbox.

If you want to apply a *watermark* effect you have 2 possibilities:

- Use the new HTML 5 [placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) (this obviously assumes that the client browser supports it):

  ```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.QualityM1s, New With { Key .placeholder = "some default text"})
  ```
- Use javascript. For example there are [many jQuery watermark plugins](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+watermark&oq=jquery+watermark&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...644.2657.0.2737.16.8.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.35cra7PVypQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=a2177ce5120cae1&biw=1680&bih=945).

Comment: Hi - thank you - inside my controller it says:    

' GET: /MPEmployees/Create


        Function Create() As ActionResult

            Return View()

        End Function

If I try to reference model inside that part of code, it just advises it's not been defined.

Comment: This means that your controller action is wrong. Your view is strongly typed to some model (at the top of your view you have a `@ModelType` directive). You need to pass an instance of this model to the view. Like this: `Dim model = New SomeModel() model.QualityM1s = "some default text" return View(model)`.